# Microsoft.Toolkit.Diagnostics Or CommunityTookit.Diagnostics

Tags: c#, nuget

I have noticed that there are two NuGet packages that have Guard and ThrowHelper classes in them. Microsoft.Toolkit.Diagnostics and CommunityToolkit.Diagnostics. Which one is the right one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After making the same question in the project's repository, I have discovered that CommunityToolkit will be the permanent home of Guard and ThrowHelper. Here is that discussion [Community Toolkit](https://github.com/communitytoolkit/dotnet/discussions/234)